# Why is my dynamically created TabPage not showing?

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I'm working with a TabControl and TabPages. I have an already built out TabPage with a whole bunch of Controls in it, including GroupBoxes. I have made a function to be able to clone that TabPage's controls into a new one. So I make the new TabPage, then clone all of the first TabPage's controls into the new one (Including the GroupBoxes' controls inside the new GroupBoxes'), then add the new TabPage into the TabControl and Select it.

```cs
Button BT_Delete = new Button {
    BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLight,
    Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 377),
    Name = "BT_Delete",
    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23),
    TabIndex = 1002,
    Text = "Delete",
    UseVisualStyleBackColor = false
};
Button BT_Save = new Button {
    BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLight,
    Location = new System.Drawing.Point(87, 377),
    Name = "BT_Save",
    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23),
    TabIndex = 1001,
    Text = "Save",
    UseVisualStyleBackColor = false
};
Label LBL_Status = new Label {
    AutoSize = true,
    Location = new System.Drawing.Point(168, 382),
    Name = "LBL_Status",
    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 13),
    TabIndex = 1003,
    Text = "Ready."
};
Button BT_Close = new Button {
    BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLight,
    Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1059, 377),
    Name = "BT_Close",
    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23),
    TabIndex = 1003,
    Text = "Close",
    UseVisualStyleBackColor = false
};

TabPage newPage = new TabPage("Text");
newPage.Name = "Name"

ClonePage(TCP_New.Controls, newPage.Controls);
newPage.Controls.Add(BT_Delete);
newPage.Controls.Add(BT_Save);
newPage.Controls.Add(LBL_Status);
newPage.Controls.Add(BT_Close);
TC_Main.TabPages.Add(newPage);
TC_Main.SelectTab(newPage);
```

Now that works fine, the new TabPage is added in the TabControl, it shows fine, and I can manipulate data as well.

Now the problem is that if I add another one using the exact same function, the GroupBoxes and their content won't show up. The Buttons and the Label however are working fine. I can see them, and interact with them. So my idea is that the issue is coming from my cloning of the GroupBoxes and their content but I can't figure out where or why.

Here is my ControlCollection (of the TabPage) cloning function :

```cs
private void ClonePage(Control.ControlCollection from, Control.ControlCollection to) {
    foreach (Control c in from) {
        if (c is GroupBox) {
            GroupBox gbx = (c as GroupBox).Clone();
            to.Add(gbx);

            foreach (Control child in (c as GroupBox).Controls) {
                if (child is Label) {
                    Label lbl = (child as Label).Clone();
                    gbx.Controls.Add(lbl);
                } else if (child is TextBox) {
                    TextBox tbx = (child as TextBox).Clone();
                    gbx.Controls.Add(tbx);
                } else if (child is CheckBox) {
                    CheckBox cbx = (child as CheckBox).Clone();
                    gbx.Controls.Add(cbx);
                } else if (child is NumericUpDown) {
                    NumericUpDown nup = (child as NumericUpDown).Clone();
                    gbx.Controls.Add(nup);
                } else if (child is Button) {
                    Button btn = (child as Button).Clone();
                    gbx.Controls.Add(btn);
                } else if (child is ComboBox) {
                    ComboBox cbb = (child as ComboBox).Clone();
                    gbx.Controls.Add(cbb);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Clone() function :

```cs
public static T Clone<T>(this T controlToClone) where T : Control {
    PropertyInfo[] controlProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    T instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

    if (controlToClone is ComboBox) {
        foreach (string i in (controlToClone as ComboBox).Items) {
            (instance as ComboBox).Items.Add(i);
        }
    }

    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in controlProperties) {
        if (propInfo.CanWrite) {
            if (propInfo.Name != "WindowTarget") {
                propInfo.SetValue(instance, propInfo.GetValue(controlToClone, null), null);
            }
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm stuck here.

Comment: There is no practical way to clone a Control object.  It has many dozens of fields and properties that critically depend on runtime state.  You'll for instance copy the Handle property, very very bad.  It is much simpler than that, all you have to do is run the exact same code again.  So you get a new set of Button and Label objects.  Just move that code into another method that returns a TabPage object.  Note how the InitializeComponent() method of a UserControl works that way as well.  Which is the other good way to do it, a UC for the TabPage content.

Comment: Ok so it isn't as simple as I thought x)
So if I make a function that creates a new object of the type I need then applies just the properties I want it will work ?

Comment: That's what you already do when you create the Buttons and Label objects.  So ought to be good enough as-is to get another TabPage with the same set of controls having the same properties.  I can't guess what other properties you might want to set, other than the TabPage.Name perhaps.  Do take a look at UserControl.